SQL - Is there a shorthand to refer to columns with same prefix and incrementing suffix (like, var1, var2, var3...) in a where statement?
I'm looking to do something like this:
create or replace table patients as
select distinct id
from dataset
where value in (var1:var30)
; 

I could make a temp table that contains just the variable names and use a subquery in my main query, but I'd ideally like to never have to type out all 30 variables. Even if I were to use an array, I still don't know if I can ever get around having to type them all out.
Thanks in advance for your time! Even just replying "not that I know of" is incredibly helpful!

I am afraid your question is not clear + you didn't tag your database.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
